# JS or jQuery approach to arrange json into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm struggling with a frontend processing of a response from a server that spews out the event reviews in the season. There can be multiple reviewers for the same event and the simplified version of `response` looks like this:

```
[{"id":"3","reviewer_id":"4","event_id":"3","review":"a"},
{"id":"19","reviewer_id":"3","event_id":"4","review":"b"},
{"id":"20","reviewer_id":"1","event_id":"4","review":"b"}]
```

I want to make and array with events where array index would be defined by `event_id`, therefore I do something like this:

```
var events = new Array();//define the recipient array
$.each(response, function(index, row) {
    if (!(jQuery.isArray(events[Number(row.event_id)]))) {//if a variable by this index is not array then...
        var events [Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();// ...declare it as array, I get error thrown here: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["
    } 
    events[Number(row.event_id)].push(row);//push current row into appropriate recipient array member
});
```

As noted in the code, I have an error thrown

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in line 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put a `var` in front of it.

```
var events [Number(row.event_id)] = ...
```

Remove the `var` and the error will go away

```
events [Number(row.event_id)] = ...
```

The reason is that keyword `var` is used to define a new variable, and when defining a new variable, you cannot create a property to that variable (such as `Number(row.event_id)`).

Besides, `events` has already been defined earlier. You should not define `events` again for your function to work correctly.

```js
var response = [{"id":"3","reviewer_id":"4","event_id":"3","review":"a"},
{"id":"19","reviewer_id":"3","event_id":"4","review":"b"},
{"id":"20","reviewer_id":"1","event_id":"4","review":"b"}];

var events = new Array();//define the recipient array
$.each(response, function(index, row) {
    if (!(jQuery.isArray(events[Number(row.event_id)]))) {//if a variable by this index is not array then...
        events [Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();// ...declare it as array, I get error thrown here: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["
    } 
    events[Number(row.event_id)].push(row);//push current row into appropriate recipient array member
});

console.log(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**By the way**

JavaScript does not support multidimensional array. Only objects.

Comment: Thank you, do you by chance know why am I getting an empty first element of the array? so that `events` looks like `[empty × 3, Array(1), Array(2), ... ]` with `console.log()`

Comment: because of `events[Number(row.event_id)].push(row)`. The smallest `event_id` is `3`, but as an array, `events` should have values in index `0, 1, 2` but these are missing. So there is `empty x 3`

Comment: just use `var events = {}` will solve your problem but it is not an array anymore. Still, it can be parsed into multidimensional array in PHP server. Besides, it seems to be a more appropriate approach than your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error on this line:

```
var events [Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();
```

You need to change this to:

```
events[Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();
```

You don't need `var` declaration for adding a property in an object, or adding an element in an array. That's a syntax error. Following is a working example of your code:

```js
var response = [{
    "id": "3",
    "reviewer_id": "4",
    "event_id": "3",
    "review": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "19",
    "reviewer_id": "3",
    "event_id": "4",
    "review": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "reviewer_id": "1",
    "event_id": "4",
    "review": "b"
  }
];

var events = new Array();

$.each(response, function(index, row) {
  if (!(jQuery.isArray(events[Number(row.event_id)]))) {
    events[Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();
  }
  events[Number(row.event_id)].push(row);
});

console.log(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666110/js-or-jquery-approach-to-arrange-json-into-multidimensional-array/49666247#
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be this line

```
var events [Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();
```

Which appears to be trying to declare a variable called `events` (which is already declared above) and simultaneously assign an new array to a specific index.

Remove `var` and it should resolve the syntax error.

```
events [Number(row.event_id)] = new Array();
```